# 2004 Tahoe Conking, Glub Glub Glub

Tags: engine, chevrolet, rough-idle, stall, tahoe

My 2004 Tahoe is not running well and conked out on me the other day.  I just had it repaired for some other reasons and the repair shop suggested we needed to have spark plugs replaced so it will run better.  However, before then, it ran fine.  I said no on the spark plugs, but now that I have it back it is running poor and I don't know how to describe it...  It is glubbing, missing, on the verge of conking. The same thing happened to our minivan years ago and in that case, it was simply an air flow tube that was not pushed in all the way and once we pushed it in, all was well again.

Comment: When was the last time spark plugs were replaced? The plugs it self are not that expensive, but in some v8 engines they are harder to access. Might be a good idea to get the plugs replaced  if they are easy to access.

Comment: I don't think ever @rana.

Comment: Please help us help you by hooking it up to a scan tool to see if there are any codes and understand what the fuel trims are like. I'd recommend inspecting the spark plugs to see if they really need replacing before splurging money on brand new ones.

Comment: How many miles on your Tahoe? If over 100k, you need to do a complete tune up, to include plugs, wires, and O2 sensors, then cleaning all of the MAF and IAC valves. The 2004 GM Trucks had a 100k tune up for these items, so is why I am suggesting them straight out. Also, a video of what it's doing would be of great assistance ... one with good audio. ***AND*** as @Zaid said, get it scanned so you know what's going on.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply everyone.  On a Tahoe, is it relatively easy to do these mods myself?

Comment: @CRAIG - That is relative to your mechanical abilities. Would be easy for me, though I've done the work before. If the O2 sensors are stuck/sticking in their bung, it can become a nightmare. The rest of it is pretty much straight forward, but takes time and patience.

Comment: @CRAIG   Have you been able to goto your local auto parts store and have them read any error codes on your vehicle with one of their scan tools?

Comment: OK. So, an update....  Another thing I have noticed since I took it in is, I have been getting messages that the Oil Pressure is Low and that it is low on oil.  Since I got it back which was right before Thanksgiving, I have had to add almost 4 quarts of oil.  (The mechanics had told me that there was an oil leak or two, but nothing serious.  So, I took it somewhere else today and they want to charge me $1200 for the following (codes included): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GNBFaKRM4X-O5BCaszGbniF8Lnh85SWvV_I1CpOjcLc/edit?usp=sharing
Thanks! @BobCross

Comment: You should put those codes directly in the text of the original question.

Comment: Can you modify your question to reflect all of the comment data you've provided?  Too painful working it all out in the comments.  Obviously this 'thing' is getting attention based upon all the commentary.

Comment: ....and yes.  +1 for the 'glub glub glub' from me as well.    :)

Answer (score 2):

The most common cause of this complex of symptoms is leaking intake manifold gaskets. Test for this by spraying a squirt of carburetor cleaner up and around the intake manifold. If the engine smooths out for a few seconds then there is a leak.

The second most common cause is failure of the mass air flow sensor (MAF). I offer no quick tests for this part short of swapping in a new one. Testing is done with graphing scan tool data and having an experience person interpret this data.

Other failures of possible, but this covers 90% of the problems of this type on this engine.